# IE 11 doesn't preload while preloading with 500+ images(600x400)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I am preloading thousands of images and once preloaded then showing them to the user at a time.

So to achieve this i keep these all images in cache and fetching them on demand. The images are of 600x400 dimensions.

The problem we have is, it stops preloading after random interval meaning if I preload 1000 images, it breaks around 400, 450, 370, 550 images respectively.

So is there any limitation in IE or any other way to handle such situations.

NOTE: It works 99% in other browsers like safari, chrome, Mozilla with same network and hardware.

Here is the below code:

```
function callImage(url){ 
    var tempImage; tempImage.src = url; 
    tempImage.onload = function () { } 
    return tempImage; 
} 
AllImageSources = ["image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", ..., image3000.jpg];
for(var i=0;i<AllImageSources.length;i++) { 
    var tempImage = callImage(AllImageSources[i]);
    //code to append tempImage to DOM
}
```

Comment: What is the total size of all the images??

Comment: what method are you using to preload these images

Comment: @answer99, total size of the images is 670 MB

Comment: @Jaromanda X, Images are coming from php page so for us it's just a src. Using a forloop we are caching all images (using new Image())

Comment: did you tried the compressing the images.... that 670mb size images are too heavy to load to image...

Comment: It would help if we saw your preloader code.

Comment: @Ishettyl function callImage(url){
var tempImage;
    tempImage.src = url;
    tempImage.onload = function () {
        

    }
return tempImage;
}

AllImageSources = ["image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", ..., image3000.jpg];
for(var i=0;i<AllImageSources.length;i++){
var tempImage = callImage(AllImageSources[i]);
//code to append tempImage to DOM
}

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to preload only a few at the time and when the user proceeds to the next image load some more?

Comment: How can i compress the images.... @answer99

Comment: @Esko, Your point is correct but even at that time the RAM, cache and DOM size will remain the same.

Comment: you will get online tools.... like http://compressnow.com/  (or)

you can download pngoptimiser exe file... that is the good option...

Comment: @answer99: Can we do this with javascript or jquery

Comment: Now there is no way to compress images by javascript or jquery.

Comment: you can remove image `src` from the array, when its **DOM** is loaded then : iterate and check through remaining items before index of loaded image recursively until the array is empty. So all your images are loaded.

Comment: loading 500 images at once is both insane and useless. try doing the same with chunks of 50

Comment: @answer99 - nonsense. You can set the compression used when calling canvas.toDataURL that is outputting a jpg. This does indeed allow you to compress a jpg. I do concede that the equivalent operation is unavailable for png (or any other format)

Comment: @Ramin Omrani: Can you explain somemore, i didn't understand, otherwise you can modify my existing code.